# Get navigation bar orientation (left/right) on Nexus (7.1.1)

Tags: android

In landscape mode, Android 7.1 introduced repositioning of softbuttons bar when device is rotated.
Before 7.1 it was placed always on the right side of view, no matter how you hold your phone.

In my app I used to shrink (and move) the view by softbuttons bar width, like this:

```
getGameActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRealMetrics(real);
```

but now I need to know whether bar is on right or left side of the view.
Yep, for sure I can check device rotation and android version, but I consider this method as not truly reliable.

Is there any way to know if my navigation bar positioned at the left or right side of my current view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I solved the problem.

To handle orientation change:

```
    android.view.OrientationEventListener mOrientationEventListener = new android.view.OrientationEventListener(this, android.hardware.SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL)
    {
        @Override
        public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {

            if (orientation > 60 && orientation < 120) {
                orientation = 0;
            } else if (orientation > 240 && orientation < 300) {
                orientation = 1;
            } else {
                return;
            }

            if (prevOrientation != orientation) {
                Log.d("", "onOrientationChanged NEW " + orientation);

                prevOrientation = orientation;

                Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                       // (notify your code that orientation changed)
                    }
                };
                handler.postDelayed(r, 1200);
            }
        }
    };

    if(mOrientationEventListener.canDetectOrientation()) {
        mOrientationEventListener.enable();
    }
```

and then, to check if navigation bar is on the left side:

```
    int rotation =  getGameActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
    int reqOr = getGameActivity().getRequestedOrientation();

    String aVerReleaseStr = Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
    int dotInd = aVerReleaseStr.indexOf(".");
    if (dotInd >= 0) {
        aVerReleaseStr = aVerReleaseStr.replaceAll("\\.", "");
        aVerReleaseStr = new StringBuffer(aVerReleaseStr).insert(dotInd, ".").toString();
    }

    float androidVer = Float.parseFloat(aVerReleaseStr);
    if (rotation == 3 && reqOr == 6 && androidVer >= 7.1) {
       // buttons are on the left side.
    }
```

Comment: Instead of parsing the Android version release string, you can simply lookup the `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` property. 7.1 is 25 API level.